# Python Pandas date-time conversion or encoding issue

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, encoding, psycopg2

I am looking to upload CSV data via `pd.read_csv`.
In the initial creation of this thread, I believed the issue was related to the conversion of date-time values in the data as it appeared that while the conversion of the data to a Python readable format was performed correctly until insertion of the data to the PostgreSQL, now I believe the culprit for the errors might be the encoding.  My database is encoded `utf-8`.The data has Turkish and German characters in columns such as the first and last name as well as address related fields.

The snippet reads in the CSV file into a dataframe, then the first for-loop iterates over all columns in the dataframe defined as date columns (`date_cols`). Then every cell that is in date column is checked for the date-format and is converted into a readable python date-format as the initial data is received in the format mm.dd.yyyy.

This is an excerpt of the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8-sig -*-
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
import locale
locale.getpreferredencoding(False)
import pandas as pd
import datetime import datetime
import datetime import date

df = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding='ISO 8859-9', sep=';', header=0)
for col in date_cols:
    if col in df.columns:

        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            f_date = df.ix[index, col]
            if isinstance(f_date, unicode):
                f_date = datetime.strftime(pd.to_datetime(f_date), '%Y-%m-%d')
                df.ix[index, col] = f_date
                if f_date > str(pd.Timestamp.max.date()):
                    df.ix[index, col] = pd.Timestamp.max

                else:
                    df.ix[index, col] = f_date.date()

dict_items = df.to_dict(orient='records')

connection.execute(table.insert(), dict_items)
```

The output for the conversions is:

```
print(f_date) 02.03.1983
print(pd.to_datetime(f_date)) 1983-03-02 00:00:00
print(py_date) 1983-03-02
```

The date seems to be correct in the format yyyy-mm-dd (month is in middle i.e) but when ingested to `psycopg2` the value is flipped to `1969-02-03`. So the format is now yyyy-dd-mm.

The problem i'm trying to solve is the following error, where the date-format sent to the database is yyyy-dd-mm instead of yyyy-mm-ddI am trying to load this data into a PostgreSQL database with the format `1983-03-02`:

`(<class 'sqlalchemy.exc.DataError'>, DataError('(psycopg2.DataError) invalid input syntax for type date: ""\nLINE 1: ...@asp.de\', \'1983-02-03\'::date,`

As I am beginning to this might be an encoding error and not a date-time conversion issue, I've tried the following two scenarios.

Scenario 1 (Encode File as ISO 8859-1 in text editor):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8-*-
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("ISO 8859-1")
df = pd.read_csv(full_path, encoding='ISO 8859-1', sep=';')
```

The error is:

```
(<class 'sqlalchemy.exc.DataError'>, DataError('(psycopg2.DataError) invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x80\n
```

Scenario 2 (Encode File as utf-8 in text editor):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8-*-
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
df = pd.read_csv(full_path, encoding='utf-8', sep=';')
```

The error I receive is:

```
(<class 'sqlalchemy.exc.DataError'>, DataError('(psycopg2.DataError) invalid input syntax for type date: ""\nLINE 1: ...@asp.de\', \'1983-02-03\'::date
```

Thanks

Comment: Is that you have the problem that date and month is swapped?

Comment: @Tai - yes the day and month are swapped, not in the dataframe nor in the conversion to a `df.to_dict(orient='records')`. It seems this is happening when i execute the  `table.insert()` object.

Comment: Seems that the reason for the error are empty values in fields that are of type - character varying, dates etc and causing conflict with the database. So filling those with values that are 'acceptable' fixes this error.